# Instagram API search by tag shows photos without said tag

Tags: api, instagram, hashtag

I´m querying the Instagram tag endpoint like so:
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/dog/media/recent?access_token=mytoken

In the response some of the results posts shown have in the tags array the tag I searched:

```
...
"tags": ["life", "art", "nature", "food", "photo", "hair", "lol", "dog", ...],
...
```

However I can't seem to find where the tag came from. Is not on the caption or the comments.

Also lots of the tags aren't present either. 
This is the case for some posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a media only returns 8 or so actual comment objects, even if the count is much higher, you will not always see where the tag is created.  So if you pull medias with 100 comments, you may see all kinds of tags in the tag object that you do not see in comment text.

If you need to, you can use the comments endpoint to go through all the comments for a media id.